# "What did he say is" OR "What did he say was"

Tags: past-tense, reported-speech

Actually I want to narrate my friend about what Jhon said to me.

Timing: Jhon and I talked yesterday, and know I am explaining this to my friend.

What I have to say to my friend "What did he say is" OR "What did he say was"

Comment: *What he said was..*

Answer (score 1):

You would normally say "What he *said* was..."

It's always *was* because he said the thing *then*, back in the past.

It is possible to use *do* for emphasis, as in "What he *did say* was..."; this is called the [**emphatic do**](http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/Emphatic-do.htm).  You would normally use it in a context like, "He didn't say that.  But what he *did* say was..."